# Bad aliasing for red

Tags: graphics, display, monitor, appearance, antialiasing

I am using Ubuntu 18.4, XFCE, and a new monitor.

While the monitor seems to work fine in windows, and in Linux for most purposes, it does something that I do not understand with the anti-aliasing for red, not just fonts, but red in general.

For example, here all the circles should be similarly round, but the red one has more the shape of a plus `+` symbol, and is less round. Anti-aliasing settings seem to do nothing, and they would be only for fonts.

[image]

The color bleeding that you see on red and blue is there. I can see it by eye better than I can capture in a photo. Similarly, parentheses look fine except if they happen to be red.

[image]

This happens both in images and fonts, although in fonts it is more annoying. I have not noticed anything similar in windows (same hardware, dual boot), which leads me to believe that it is some issue at the software level.

What could be the reason and how could I fix this?

PD: adding another picture. It may be a subpixel aliasing problem, but I cannot find the corresponding setting other than for fonts (the problem is in everything red, and less noticeably blue, not just fonts).[image]

Comment: All the information that I find on google refers to anti-aliasing for text, but the problem is not text, is red, both text and images. This is very confusing, TBH.

Comment: Is the screen set at native resolution?

Comment: yes, that's the first thing I have set up.

Comment: BTW: I am using HDMI, if that makes any difference.

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April '21)

Comment: Interesting, I did not notice flavors do not have the 5 years support of the regular LTS. I may as well install 20.04 and see if that fixes it. I have to put together the time for it in a number of areas...

Comment: With some more time to check it up, I have noticed that the monitor would be by default to 100Hz, and lowering that to 75 or 60Hz solved the problem.

Comment: @Trylks I encountred same issue on my monitor too. While lowering from 60HZ to 30HZ solved the issue, I do not see it happen to macOS or Windows at 60HZ.